# Where do javascript and css files go in a laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Where should static javascript and css files in a Laravel 4 application.  For the sake of my own understanding, I'm not interested in using any sort of assets or packages yet.

I tried putting them under `public/js` and `public/packages` to no avail, getting the following 404 errors in my page:

```
GET http://localhost/~myuser/mytest/packages/test2.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/~myuser/mytest/js/mytest.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is what my `.htaccess` file looks like for reference:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~myuser/mytest/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: [laravel documentation](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All assets should be placed in the `public` folder

```
public/js
public/css
public/fonts
public/images
```

You can access the assets using the `asset()` method or the Laravel HTML helper methods `HTML::script` and `HTML::style`. 
i.e to include Javascript file:

```
 - <script src="{{ asset('js/yourfile.js') }}"></script>

 - {{ HTML::script('js/yourfile.js') }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Yani How can I point different servers in asset function? For example, I want to have `asset('192.168.2.4/jscr.js')` in development and `asset('s.mysite/jscr.js')` in production.

Comment: @user2356198 `asset()` is not designed to support external scripts from outside your project folder. In your case, I'd write a helper function (i.e `myAsset("jscrs.js")`) and define a environment variable in your .env file which will be different in local and production environments.

Comment: @Yani I mean I would use asset in master blade file, not in js file.

Comment: @user2356198 not sure what you mean by that. You're more than welcome to post a new question on StackOverflow with some of your code and send me a link to it so I can try and answer..

Answer (score 2):

Inside the laravel folder you got public folder put css and js files here and access like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{{$title}}</title>
        {{HTML::style('css/style.css')}}
    </head>
    <body>
        @include('layouts.nav')      
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you need to include some specific .js files for some views and then other .js files for other views? How do you handle or organize that?